# Mesos agent memory control with resource flag

Tags: mesos

When I was trying to limit memory on mesos agent with --resource flag, it seems doesn't work at all. The slave can still use all the cpus and memory on virtual machine. Did I use it wrong?

Comment: Can you please supply how you added the --resources flag in your command or the slave entry from the processlist?

Comment: What isolators are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By default Mesos Conterneizer uses PSOIX [isolators](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/#isolators) (`posix/cpu`,`posix/mem`) since they are not a real isolator it's recomended to use cgroups isolators instead ([`cgroups/cpu`](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/isolators/cgroups-cpu/),`cgroups/mem`).

> `--isolation=VALUE`   Isolation mechanisms to use, e.g., `posix/cpu,posix/mem` (or `windows/cpu,windows/mem` if you are on Windows), or `cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem`, or `network/port_mapping` (configure with flag: `--with-network-isolator` to enable), or `gpu/nvidia` for nvidia specific gpu isolation, or load an alternate isolator module using the --modules flag. If `cgroups/all` is specified, any other cgroups related isolation options (e.g., `cgroups/cpu`) will be ignored, and all the local enabled cgroups subsystems on the agent host will be automatically loaded by the cgroups isolator. Note that this flag is only relevant for the Mesos Containerizer. (default: `windows/cpu,windows/mem` on Windows; `posix/cpu,posix/mem` on other platforms)